# How can I solve this vector algebra problem?

Tags: vectors

Suppose that

$$\vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{s} \times \vec{v}}{\lVert \vec{s}\rVert^2}$$

How do I solve for $\vec{s}$?

Comment: You can't. You know that $s$ lies in the plane normal to $\omega$. If the angle between $v$ and $s$ is $\theta$, then $|\omega|=\frac{|v|\sin\theta}{|s|}$. But you have no way of figuring out $|s|$ and $\sin\theta$ separately without more information.

Comment: @almagest An equation may have more than one solution, that does not mean you can't describe the set of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem to have a solution, $\vec{\omega}$ has to be orthogonal to both $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{v}$, hence you can write $\vec{s}$ as a linear combination of $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}$, and $\vec{v}$, which are orthogonal to $\vec{\omega}$, and additionally orthogonal to each other (thus they form a basis of the plane orthogonal to $\vec{\omega}$).

That is:

$$\vec{s}=\alpha\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}+\beta\vec{v}$$

But you need also to have

$$\frac{\vec{s}\times\vec v}{\lVert \vec{s}\rVert^2}=\frac{\alpha(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v})\times\vec v}{\lVert \vec{s}\rVert^2}=\vec\omega$$

Or by expanding the "triple product" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Triple_product_expansion)):
$$\frac{\alpha}{\lVert \vec{s}\rVert^2}\left(\vec{v}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\omega})-\vec{\omega}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})\right)=\vec\omega$$

That is,

$$\alpha=-\frac{\lVert \vec{s}\rVert^2}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}=-\frac{\lVert \vec{s}\rVert^2}{\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^2}$$

And $\beta$ remains arbitrary: when there is a solution, there are actually infinitely many solutions.

Comment: If $\Delta \theta$ is the difference in angle between $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{v}$ it is the case that $ \lVert \vec{s} \rVert = \frac{\lVert \vec{\omega} \rVert \lVert \vec{v} \rVert \sin \Delta \theta}{\lVert \vec{\omega} \rVert^2} $ right? But there are infinitely many solutions of the same magnitude but that point in different directions?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus The solutions are found by adding an arbitrary multiple of $\vec v$ to $\vec s$: both magnitude and direction change.

Comment: $ \lVert \vec{\omega} \rVert = \frac{\lVert \vec{s} \rVert \lVert \vec{v} \rVert \sin \Delta \theta}{\lVert \vec{s} \rVert^2} $

$ \lVert \vec{\omega} \rVert = \frac{ \lVert \vec{v} \rVert \sin \Delta \theta}{\lVert \vec{s} \rVert} $

$ \lVert \vec{s} \rVert = \frac{ \lVert \vec{v} \rVert \sin \Delta \theta}{\lVert \vec{\omega} \rVert} $ So I guess the magnitude depends upon the angle.